# Default worksheet on when opening excel workbook without using vba code?

Tags: excel

Is there any way to Default worksheet on when opening excel workbook without using vba code?
Because Macros are not support when we open excel file in web.

I have tried vba code to make default worksheet but it not working when opening excel workbook via web.

`Private Sub Workbook_Open() Worksheets("StartSheet").Activate End Sub`

Comment: The "default" worksheet is the one that was selected when the file was last saved. At least that's how desktop Excel 2010 behaves. Is this not the case with the web version?

Comment: no in web also behaves same. But the excel is in sharepoint and there is many users can access to the report. if anyone has opened any other worksheets and closed the file then it was opening the same worksheet when others opening the excel.  That's why we need to make first sheet as default.

Comment: Create a link to the excel file which includes the tab you want them to access first, then have the users of the document click on that link to access the file: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/opening-specific-tab-in-excel-online/7ea00b32-6329-40ba-b671-ae9e66a30ab1